# Check if a page is a parent or if it's a child page?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to check if a page is a parent or if it's a child page?

I have my pages set up like this:

-- Parent

---- Child page 1

---- Child page 2

etc.

I want to show a certain menu if it's a parent page and a different menu if it's on the child page.

I know I can do something like below but I want to make it a bit more dynamic without including specific page ID's.

```
<?php
if ($post->post_parent == '100') { // if current page is child of page with page ID 100
   // show image X 
}
?>
```

Comment: How do you want to identify 'parent' then?

Comment: @alexjamesbrown Is there a way to do something like `is_parent`/`is_child`?

Comment: What do you call parent? Do you include() the child in the parent? Or do you have any other kind of relation? Is it only a directories structure?

Comment: @cheesemacfly I want to show certain content on the parent page then different content on the child page without having to use 2 separate templates.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can test if the post is a subpage like this:
*(from http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)*

```
<?php

global $post;     // if outside the loop

if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent ) {
    // This is a subpage

} else {
    // This is not a subpage
}
?>
```

Comment: Why this works - `$post->post_parent` contains integer with Parent Post ID (default 0) - default value means no parent. `0` in condition is evaluated as **FALSE**, other numbers (>0) are evaluated as **TRUE**.

Answer (score 7):

Put this function in the functions.php file of your theme.

```
function is_page_child($pid) {// $pid = The ID of the page we're looking for pages underneath
  global $post;         // load details about this page
  $anc = get_post_ancestors( $post->ID );
  foreach($anc as $ancestor) {
      if(is_page() && $ancestor == $pid) {
          return true;
      }
  }
  if(is_page()&&(is_page($pid)))
     return true;   // we're at the page or at a sub page
  else
      return false;  // we're elsewhere
};
```

Then you can use it:

```
<?php 
    if(is_page_child(100)) {
        // show image X 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: with using "get_post_ancestors" you can check even grand children pages for level 1 post-ids - this helped me making chapter-body classes and having different css colors for different level 1 parents/grand parents!

Comment: '''
function themeName_body_class($classes){
  $classNames = array();
  $post = get_post();
  $parents = get_post_ancestors($post);
  $parents[] = $post->ID;
  
  if ( !empty($parents) ) {
    foreach ( $parents as $parentID ) {
      if ( $parentID === 8 ) {
        $classNames[] = 'my-special-className';
      }
      if ( $parentID === 11 ) {
        $classNames[] = 'my-other-special-className';
      }
    }
  }
  // echo var_dump($classes);
  return array_merge( $classes, $classNames );
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'themeName_body_class');'''

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question but I was searching for this same question and couldn't find a clear and simple answer until I came up with this one. My answer doesn't answer his explanation but it answers the main question which is what I was looking for.

This checks whether a page is a child or a parent and allows you to show, for example a sidebar menu, only on pages that are either a child or a parent and not on pages that do not have a parent nor children.

```
<?php 
   global $post;    
   $children = get_pages( array( 'child_of' => $post->ID ) );
   if ( is_page() && ($post->post_parent || count( $children ) > 0  )) : 
?>
```

Answer (score 7):

For Wordpress, you can simply check:

```
<?php 
  if (wp_get_post_parent_id(get_the_ID())) {
    echo "I am a child page";
  } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **get_pages()** function. it takes an associative array as an argument. you can give that array **'child_of' => get_the_ID()** to get the children of the current page, and if it hasn't any children the whole **get_pages()** function will return false, otherwise it will return a value that evaluates to true, which can be assigned to a variable to use as a conditional in an if statement.

```
$iAmParent = get_pages(array('child_of' => get_the_ID()));
```