# What does this Wordpress PHP code mean?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

So I don't really know PHP except for a few chapters in a book I read. (And things I look up). I'm trying to learn it as I go along because the book on PHP that I have is frustrating because it doesn't go over much that is relevant to what I'm doing.

I've also got a book on building wordpress themes that has lots of php. One of the following bits of code is in it. I understand functions, and global variables, but I am still lost as to understanding what this code means. I think part of the problem is that the code is (hooking?) into wordpress and that's confusing me. For example where does the variable $post come from, is that already in wordpress? Anyway I was wondering if someone could explain this code to me in simple terms:

```
function page_is_parent() {
global $post;
$pages = get_pages('child_of'.$post ->ID;
return count($pages);
}
```

Comment: The code you've pasted will fail in any case. You should ideally look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13916941/2518525

Answer (score 0):

Gets the number of pages that are a child of a specific parent page.